# How to edit checkout text in magento 1.9

Tags: magento

I would like to edit text on the checkout site in Magento (like 'Billing Information', 'Checkout Method',...). I am using Magento 1.9. can somebody please help me find the right file for this?
I have searched everywhere and also read previous posts, but i cant find files.

Comment: Do you want to change the text Billing Information to another ?

Comment: Are you aware about path hints in Magento, if you are you can follow the path of block and perform this part.

Answer (score 1):

All of your checkout files are in

```
app > design > frontend > [package] > [theme] > checkout
```

If you don't have a theme installed you can copy the files from the base package into a new blank package or theme. You shouldn't edit the base package.

Any easy way to find out what file you need to edit is by user the Template Path Hints. You can turn this on by going to system > configuration > developer in the admin. You then need to switch the 'current configuration scope' to the store you want to edit and not the 'default config'. You should then see a menu on the right called 'debug' with a Template Path Hints option. Turn that on and then on the frontend of your site you'll see lots of red outlines indicating what template path you need to edit.

Comment: I was unable to get Template Path Hints working but you pointed me in the right direction. I changed all in the 'template' and 'base' folders. I know i shouldn't say thank you (according to the propositions), but i will try anyway - thank you Adam.